# Type of Generic

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Can I somehow check a type of `T`. I want to check that this type is `Array` or something else.

```
func request<T: Mappable>(completionHandler: (Result<T>) -> Void) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to overload the method, like so:

```
private func request<T: Mappable>(isArray: Bool, completionHandler: (Result<T>) -> Void) {
  if isArray {
    print("is array")
  } else {
    print("is not array")
  }
}

func request<T>(completionHandler: (Result<Array<T>>) -> Void) {
  request(isArray: true, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

func request<T: Mappable>(completionHandler: (Result<T>) -> Void) {
  request(isArray: false, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

I'm assuming that somewhere you have defined:

```
extension Array: Mappable {}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really interesting :)